# How do I prevent my terminal from stopping when my discord bot is in a VC

Tags: debugging, discord, discord.js, bots, voice

I have just recently made a discord bot using discord.js. The bot I have created joins VC's and plays music. At random times my terminal just crashes when the bot tries to join a VC. How do I stop this from happening and make it continue with the code.

This is what I have got so far.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.member.voice.channel) {
    const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    connection.play(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRxSRyrTANY', { quality: 'highestaudio' },{ type: 'opus' }));
    setTimeout(() => {
    connection.disconnect();
  }, 12000); 
if (console.log.error);
  }
});
```

Also, this website (https://discordjs.guide/voice/optimisation-and-troubleshooting.html#preparing-your-bot-for-debugging) suggests that to do this

```
client.on('debug', console.log);

channel.join().then(connection => {
    connection.on('debug', console.log);
});
```

but I don't know where to put it in the code?
What do I do?

Comment: what is the error you get when the bot crashes?

Answer (score 0):

To answer a part of your question,

> but I don't know where to put it in the code? What do I do?

You can paste the code under the `client.on('message')` event.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584) is a cheat-sheet of discord events to learn more.